# Dynamically update the table when we update in the database in datatables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, datatable

When we load the page datatables are loaded perfectly.when we update any record through AJAX in datatable tables not shows any updates.
Here is mycode please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Admin demo</title>
  <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
            @import "demo_page.css";
            @import "demo_table.css";               
   </style>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">  
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">   -->
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/media/js/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.datepicker.regional[""].dateFormat = 'yy-mm-dd';
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['']);
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "aoColumns": [{
            "sWidth": "200px"
        },
        null,
        null,
        null]
    })
        .columnFilter({
        sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
        aoColumns: [{
            type: "text"
        }, {
            type: "select"
        }, {
            type: "date-range"
        },{
            type: "text"
        }]
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').on("click", "tr#dialog-confirm", function () {
        var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function () {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();
        //' + $.trim(tableData[0]) + '

        var dynamicDialog = $('<div id="MyDialog" > <div><div style="width:150px;float:left;">Amount</div><div style="float:left;">:</div><div style="width:150px;float:left;"><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" style="width:150px;"/><input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" value="'+$.trim(tableData[0])+'" style="display:none;"/></div></div><div><div style="width:150px;float:left;">Password</div><div style="float:left;">:</div><div style="width:150px;float:left;"><input type="password" name="password" id="password" style="width:150px;"/></div></div></div>');
        dynamicDialog.dialog({
            title: "Admin chips adding",
            modal: true,
            height: 250,
            width: 400,
            buttons: [{
                text: "Yes",
                click: function () 
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "html",
                        url: "Chips_AddedByAdmin.php",
                        cache: false,
                        data: {
                            username: $.trim(tableData[0]),
                            amount: $('#amount').val(),
                            password: $('#password').val()
                        },
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $('#MyDialog').html('loading please wait...');
                        },
                        success: function (htmldata) {

                            $('#MyDialog').html("You have successfully updated the database");
                            dynamicDialog.dialog("close");

                        }
                    });

                }
            }, {
                text: "No",
                click: function (e) {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }]
        });

    });
});
});//]]>  
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="example" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 150px;">UserName</th>
            <th style="width: 150px;">Email</th>
            <th style="width: 180px;">Created Date</th>
             <th style="width: 180px;">Real Chips</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 150px;">UserName</th>
            <th style="width: 150px;">Email</th>
            <th style="width: 180px;">Created Date</th>
             <th style="width: 180px;">Real Chips</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>        
    <tr id="dialog-confirm">
        <td>demo12</td>
        <td>t1@gmail.com</td>
        <td>2014-08-27 12:15:31</td>
        <td>456</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="dialog-confirm">
        <td>demo1</td>
        <td>t1@gmail.com</td>
        <td>2014-08-27 12:15:51</td>
        <td>120</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="dialog-confirm">
        <td>demo2</td>
        <td>t1@gmail.com</td>
        <td>2014-08-27 12:15:52</td>
          <td>125</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="dialog-confirm">
        <td>demo3</td>
        <td>t1@gmail.com</td>
        <td>2014-08-27 12:15:52</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="dialog-confirm">
        <td>demo4</td>
        <td>t1@gmail.com</td>
        <td>2014-08-27 12:15:52</td>
          <td>140</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="dialog-confirm">
        <td>demo5</td>
        <td>t1@gmail.com</td>
        <td>2014-08-27 12:15:52</td>
          <td>160</td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>  
</body>
</html>
```

And this my PHP script to update chips dymacilly

```
 <?php
require_once("configure.php");
echo $nickname = $_POST['username'];
echo $amount = $_POST['amount'];
echo $password = $_POST['password'];

echo $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE nickname ='admin' and password='$password';";
$rs = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($rs);
if($numrows > 0)
{

    echo $sql = "update users set real_chips=real_chips+'$amount' where nickname='$nickname';";
    $rs = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
}


?>
```

Please help me.

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar How can we call the database tables in drawDataTable()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write `document.ready` multiple times, it should be once in html.
To reload datatable from ajax request, you need to destroy existing table then redraw it again.

Put your datatable initilisation code in function say `drawDataTable` and call it when ajax request is successful. see below code.

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.datepicker.regional[""].dateFormat = 'yy-mm-dd';
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['']);

    drawDataTable = function(){
     $('#example').dataTable({
        "aoColumns": [{
            "sWidth": "200px"
        },
        null,
        null,
        null]
    })
        .columnFilter({
        sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
        aoColumns: [{
            type: "text"
        }, {
            type: "select"
        }, {
            type: "date-range"
        },{
            type: "text"
        }]
    });
   }

   // call datatable for the first time when page loads
   drawDataTable();

    $('#example').on("click", "tr#dialog-confirm", function () {
        var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function () {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();
        //' + $.trim(tableData[0]) + '

        var dynamicDialog = $('<div id="MyDialog" > <div><div style="width:150px;float:left;">Amount</div><div style="float:left;">:</div><div style="width:150px;float:left;"><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" style="width:150px;"/><input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" value="'+$.trim(tableData[0])+'" style="display:none;"/></div></div><div><div style="width:150px;float:left;">Password</div><div style="float:left;">:</div><div style="width:150px;float:left;"><input type="password" name="password" id="password" style="width:150px;"/></div></div></div>');
        dynamicDialog.dialog({
            title: "Admin chips adding",
            modal: true,
            height: 250,
            width: 400,
            buttons: [{
                text: "Yes",
                click: function () 
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "html",
                        url: "Chips_AddedByAdmin.php",
                        cache: false,
                        data: {
                            username: $.trim(tableData[0]),
                            amount: $('#amount').val(),
                            password: $('#password').val()
                        },
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $('#MyDialog').html('loading please wait...');
                        },
                        success: function (htmldata) {
                            //destroy existing datatable
                            $('#example').dataTable().fnDestroy();

                            //call datatable 
                            drawDataTable();

                            $('#MyDialog').html("You have successfully updated the database");
                            dynamicDialog.dialog("close");

                        }
                    });

                }
            }, {
                text: "No",
                click: function (e) {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }]
        });

    });
});
});
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to call php in  drawDataTable().

Comment: see this "// call datatable for the first time when page loads
   drawDataTable();" in my answer posted.

Comment: Please check the jsfiddle here is link http://jsfiddle.net/eLsknm0f/.@Bhushan Kawadkar

Answer (score 0):

You are echoing the query in your php code. Remove the "echo" from the beginning and see what happens: $sql="update users...."

When using client/server architecture, it is often useful to be able to test the server as a standalone process to see what's going on. In this case:

```
$test=array ('username'=>'test_user_name', 'amount'=>'123.45', 'password'=>'test_password');
$input = isset ($_REQUEST ['test']) ? $test : $_POST;

//  Now use $input instead of $_POST for your source
```

Now, when you call your php file with myfile.php?test, you can see the results without having to go through the client code. Posting that something "doesn't work" isn't very helpful - narrow down the area of the problem before asking for help.